# How can I force to RepositoryItemReader to read the newly inserted record or unprocessed record only

Tags: spring-batch

I have a batch job which is reading record from the Azure SQL database. The use case is there will be continuous writing of record in the database and my spring batch job has to run in every 5 min and read the record which is newly inserted and so far not has been procced from the last job . But I am not sure if there is inbuilt method in RepositoryItemReader or I have to implement hack solution for it

```
 @Bean
    public RepositoryItemReader<Booking> bookingReader() {
        RepositoryItemReader<Booking> bookingReader = new RepositoryItemReader<>();
        bookingReader.setRepository(bookingRepository);
        bookingReader.setMethodName("findAll");
        bookingReader.setSaveState(true);
        bookingReader.setPageSize(2);
        Map<String, Sort.Direction> sort = new HashMap<String, Sort.Direction>();
        bookingReader.setSort(sort);
        return bookingReader;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a column to your database called "STATUS". When the data is inserted into your table, the status should be "NOT PROCESSED". When your ItemReader reads data change the status to "IN PROCESS" when your ItemProcessor and ItemWriter completes its task change the status to "PROCESSED". In this way you can make sure your ItemReader reads only "NOT PROCESSED" data.

Note: If you are running your batch job using multiple threads using Task Executor, please use synchronized method in your reader to read 'NOT PROCESSED" records and to change the status to "IN PROGRESS". In this way you can make sure that multiple threads will not fetch the same data.

Comment: I am looking for more clean solution. Something which spring batch provide out of the box

Comment: There is nothing OOB as such. How would a spring batch application know which data was inserted recently?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.html#update-org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext-  in this link setCurrentItemCount can be helpful but I dont know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If table altering is not an option then another approach would be to use Spring Batch meta-data tables as much as you can.

Before job completion you simply store timestamp or some sort of indicator into a job execution context that tells you where to begin on next job iteration.

This can be "out of the box" solution.